# Google Cloud Storage - What is the best way to let a customer upload data to their own bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We would like to let a customer upload their docs to a bucket they have exclusive access to. We have considered:

1. **A service account**: we send them the json file and we set up their bucket so that that service account can access it.
2. **A signed url with write auths**: more complex to set-up, customers would hit an endpoint, get a signed url each time, and they can use it to POST
3. **A custom account**: could we create a legit google cloud account for them with super-narrow permissions?

We don't know what's the recommended go-to solution for that problem.

We have started implementing a **service account**, but we fear privilege escalation

Typically, they would be uploading data to the bucket using one of the available SDKs

Comment: You could create a new project but you would still need to send the credentials of some form. Edit your post and include details on how they will access the bucket (gcloud, HTML forms, custom code, etc). Typically, you would add their user email address to IAM granting them permission to the bucket. They would log into their Google account to fetch OAuth tokens.

Comment: Thanks, edited. They would use the SDK

Comment: If they are using the SDK, you can add their email address to the bucket's IAM and they can authenticate using `gcloud auth application-default login`. Review how Google Cloud `ADC` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> If they are using the SDK, you can add their email address to the bucket's IAM and they can authenticate using gcloud auth application-default login. Review how Google Cloud ADC works

---

Reference:

- [Gcloud Auth Application-Default Login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)
- [Set up Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc)